# scrlttr2: How to change justified print alignment into left-justified?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignment, scrlttr2, justification

By default, `scrlttr2` seems to align letter content text as justified print.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE)**:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Alice Alison}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Fairytail-Lane 1\\12345 Cologne}


\begin{document}

    \begin{letter}{Bob Bobson\\40 Michigan Street\\US-1234 Oklahoma}

        \opening{Dear Bob,}

        \lipsum

        \closing{Best wishes}

    \end{letter}

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Description of the issue:**

How can I change the current situation (justified print) and set it as left-justified?

Comment: You could try adding `\raggedright` after the `\opening`, or try `\usepackage{ragged2e}` and see the documentation for the possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can add `\raggedright` to get what you want.

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Alice Alison}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Fairytail-Lane 1\\12345 Cologne}


\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Bob Bobson\\40 Michigan Street\\US-1234 Oklahoma}

  \opening{Dear Bob,}

  \raggedright % <======================================================
  \lipsum

  \closing{Best wishes}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

and its resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

To get a better hyphenation in the raggedright part you can use package `ragged2e` and command `\RaggedRight` like

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e} %<=============================== better hyphenation!

\setkomavar{fromname}{Alice Alison}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Fairytail-Lane 1\\12345 Cologne}


\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Bob Bobson\\40 Michigan Street\\US-1234 Oklahoma}

  \opening{Dear Bob,}

  \RaggedRight % <======================================================
  \lipsum

  \closing{Best wishes}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: resulting pdf 2]